# Default Permalink Structure for Pages

Tags: permalinks, pages

I'm trying to figure out a permalink structure for my pages (not posts) in Wordpress.

Right now, I can add a "Category Base" for posts... so, something like www.mysite.com/categorybase/post1/ or www.mysite.com/categorybase/post2/

But, if I wanted to do something similar for pages, how would I do that?
For example, www.mysite.com/pagebase/page1/ or www.mysite.com/pagebase/page2/

Anyone tried this before?

Comment: have you tried looking [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=permalink+page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you're using (ie www.mysite.com/pagebase/page1) you can:

- create a page called pagebase
- create a page called page1 and make pagebase the parent page - the url for this page will be www.mysite.com/pagepage/page1

This does mean that www.mysite.com/pagebase also exists as a browsable page, but I generally use that as a section description and section index page.

Comment: Hmm... that's an interesting and simple take.  Thanks Anu.

Comment: @Troy - if Anu's answer solved your issue would you please mark it as the answer so the question shows up as answered? Thanks.